# Когда обособлять "предположительно"?

Tags: вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая в предложении: Предположительно (,) взятку чиновник получил от гражданина...
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Указанная запятая не требуется.

Нужна ли запятая: Предположительно (,) последний агрегат ГЭС будет запущен в эксплуатацию в марте 2007 года.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Корректно обособить слово *предположительно* как вводное. *Предположительно, последний агрегат ГЭС будет запущен в эксплуатацию в марте 2007 года.*

Чем объяснить обособление и необособление слова "предположительно"?
И в первом, и во втором случае можно заменить синонимом "возможно" в качестве вводного и обособить.

Но вроде можно заменить на "по предположениям", "приблизительно", "примерно" и не обособлять.

С какой интонацией это было сказано и где было сделано логическое ударение - непонятно.

Остается разобрать структуру предложения. Какая она? Что такое структура предложения?

Очень часто это слово ставит в тупик. Каков алгоритм, чтобы разобраться раз и навсегда?

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело такое... На первый вопрос, предположительно, отвечал один специалист, на второй — другой.
Тут даже от длины предложения зависит. Чем длиннее, тем больше хочется обособить. Но это сугубое имхо.

> > Но вроде можно заменить на "по предположениям", "приблизительно", "примерно" и не обособлять.

Вот как раз если заменить на "по предположениям", то обособлять нужно точно.
Кстати, "примерно" и "приблизительно" — очень неважные синонимы для "предположительно".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь, как вы верно отметили, возможны варианты: основываясь на предположениях, догадках; и: вероятно, возможно. В спорных случаях, решение принимает автор.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба вариант в зависимости от контекста, различаются они по логическому ударению на наречии "предположительно".

1) ПредположИтельно (= по предположению) взятку чиновник получил от гражданина... , но доказАть это пока не удается (слова "предположительно" и "доказать" противопоставлены друг другу).

2) Предположительно (=вероятно, должно быть), взятку чиновник получил от гражданина.... ,   об этом, к примеру, говорят следующие факты.

Обратим внимание на то, что замена другими вводными словами-синонимами  в первом случае невозможна, там важно лексическое значение наречия "предположительно"

Answer (score 1):

1. *Предположительно взятку чиновник получил от гражданина А.*

"Предположительно" здесь относится только к слову "взятка" (= предполагаемую взятку), а суждение в целом является **утверждением**: деньги (которые вполне могут оказаться взяткой) чиновник получил от гражданина А.

2. *Предположительно, взятку чиновник получил от гражданина А.*

Здесь вводное слово "предположительно" относится к следующему за ним законченному суждению и делает всё его содержание **предположением**: взятку, которую (как мы знаем) получил чиновник, вероятно, дал ему гражданин А.

Таким образом, в обоих случаях акцент на том, *кто дал деньги*, но в первом случает это *утверждение*, во втором - *предположение*. Кроме этого, в первом варианте факт взятки только предполагается, во втором - на него ссылаются как на факт. В устной речи эти варианты различаются интонацией: во втором случае после "предположительно" нужна пауза.